# React Route component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native

in my App.tsx file i have this code

```
import React from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch} from 'react-router-dom'
import PageRender from './PageRender';


const App = () => {
  return (
    <div className='container'>
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component = {PageRender} />
          <Route exact path="/:page" component={PageRender} />
          <Route exact path="/:page/:slug" component={PageRender} />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

In the file PageRender.tsx i have:

```
import React from 'react'
import { useParams  } from 'react-router-dom'
import { IParams } from './utils/TypeScript'
import NotFound from './components/global/NotFound'

const generatePage = (name: string) => {
    /*const component = () => require(`./pages/${name}`).default
    try {
        return React.createElement(component())
    } catch (error) {
        if( error instanceof Error){
            return <NotFound />;
        }
    }*/
    return name;
}

const PageRender = () => { 

    const { page, slug }: IParams = useParams()
    let name = '';
    if(page){
        name = slug ? `${page}/[slug]` : `${page}`
    }

    return generatePage(name)
}

export default PageRender
```

Now, the code works, but I get an error in file App.tsx on component of route

in paticularthis:

> ERROR in src/App.tsx:12:38
> TS2769: No overload matches this call.
> Overload 1 of 2, '(props: (RouteProps<"/:page", { page: string; }> & OmitNative<{}, keyof RouteProps<string, { [x: string]: string | undefined; }>>) | Readonly<RouteProps<"/:page", { ...; }> & OmitNative<...>>): Route<...>', gave the following error.
> Type '() => string' is not assignable to type 'ComponentType | ComponentType<RouteComponentProps<any, StaticContext, unknown>> | undefined'.
> Overload 2 of 2, '(props: RouteProps<"/:page", { page: string; }> & OmitNative<{}, keyof RouteProps<string, { [x: string]: string | undefined; }>>,
> context: any): Route<...>', gave the following error.
> Type '() => string' is not assignable to type 'ComponentType | ComponentType<RouteComponentProps<any, StaticContext, unknown>> | undefined'.

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^12.1.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "@types/jest": "^27.4.0",
    "@types/node": "^16.11.20",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.38",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.11",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.4",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.0",
    "redux": "^4.1.0",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.9",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "typescript": "^4.5.4",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.1.7"
  }
}
```